# Pipenv not picking up Python version from asdf

Tags: python, pipenv, asdf-vm

Trying to create a `Pipfile` for a specific Python version, but pipenv fails to detect that the installed Python version is present. Using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to install and manage Python versions.

```
↪ python --version
Python 3.6.6

↪ pipenv --python 3.6.6
Warning: Python 3.6.6 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path/to/python


↪ asdf current python
3.6.6    (set by /Users/dennis/some/project/.tool-versions)
```

Answer (score 9):

Recreate the shims for the desired Python version, then try again.

```
↪ asdf update

↪ asdf reshim python 3.6.6

↪ pipenv --python 3.6.6
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even passing `pipenv --python 3.10.10`, I still get `Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.11, but you are using 3.10.10`.

Comment: @NickK9 do you have an existing `Pipfile` with an explicit `python_version` requirement that differs from the version you set with `asdf`?