# How to update Julia from command line?

Tags: julia

Is there a way to update Julia from the command line? I looked through the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/), but I couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: See the ongoing discussion here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-a-simple-julia-upgrade-command/45691/1

Comment: @MattB. Thanks for that. It looks like it's just better to delete the file and install the updated version manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest trying [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) if you are on MacOS, Linux, or Windows Subsystem for Linux (it does not have support for Windows proper, since it works in Linux-type shells). It's a generic tool for handling versions and has a Julia plugin. Once `asdf` is installed, just do

```sh
asdf plugin add julia
```

to add the `julia` plugin. Then it's very easy to add a new version of Julia. I don't have 1.4.0 installed on this computer (I do have 1.5.1 installed, which I will switch to later), so I will demonstrate by installing that:

```sh
$ asdf install julia 1.4.0
Downloading from:
https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.4/julia-1.4.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 94.3M  100 94.3M    0     0  5241k      0  0:00:18  0:00:18 --:--:-- 5932k
```

Now that it's installed, I can set it to be the default version:

```sh
$ asdf global julia 1.4.0
```

Then I just run `julia`:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.4.0 (2020-03-21)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
```

Now, if I want to change the version back to `1.5.1`, it's very easy:

```sh
$ asdf global julia 1.5.1
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.5.1 (2020-08-25)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |
```

If you want the latest version, just do `asdf install julia latest`. And to see all available versions, `asdf list all julia`. Note that you seem to need to type the patch version number, e.g. `asdf install julia 1.5.1`, not `asdf install julia 1.5`.

Comment: Hi, I installed `asdf` and ran the code `asdf global julia 1.6.1` and when I run julia, it still runs the previous version. What should I do?

Comment: I’m not sure, try `which julia` to see if it’s picking up the asdf version. Maybe you have added `julia` to your PATH some other way and it’s picking that up instead.

Comment: Hi. yeah, it's not picking up asdf julia path. How can I set julia to asdf path? Because when I check PATH, I can see asdf. So what do you suggest?

Comment: sorry, I don't check StackOverflow much so didn't see this. Maybe you've added julia somewhere earlier in the PATH than asdf? Or maybe try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517801/pipenv-not-picking-up-python-version-from-asdf